# Copiar tabelas para outro banco, mantendo os relacionamentos

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, sql-insert, relacionamento

Eu estou tentando enviar alguns registros de um banco(banco A) para outro(banco B) que contém a mesma estrutura.
São registros de 3 tabelas, 1 tabela(paciente) contém registros PRINCIPAIS e as outras 2(arquivo e agendamento) são dados COMPLEMENTARES(chave estrangeira com a PRINCIPAL).

Cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dificuldade é com os IDs. Pois o **banco A e o banco B já possuem registros e os IDs de uma já existe na outra. Eu quero ignorar os IDS da tabela de Origem, mas não posso perder o relacionamento com as outras 2 tabelas.**

Eu tentei fazer um:

```
 insert bancoB.paciente
     USANDO dados de:
 select ... bancoA.paciente
```

Mas como eu tenho os relacionamentos para levar também, na hora de fazer os inserts das tabelas filhos o ID da tabela PAI(paciente) vai se perder.

**

### Segue as propriedades das 3 tabelas:

**

Tabela principal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela filho1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela filho2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: se não é replicação pode mudar os IDS, então o que vejo que talvez ajude era, fazer um cursor que pegue os dados de "paciente", faça o insert no outro banco, pegue o novo ID e faça o insert das outras tabelas usando o novo ID, tem de ser feito um a um, por isso um cursor pode ajudar ai

Comment: Legal, eu pensei nesta estratégia, mas não consegui reproduzir, deveria ser uma procedure? tem algum exemplo de código?